# JavaScript: load file that contain include PHP fucntion in div

Tags: javascript, php

I have this situation.

*file.html*

```
.......
<div id="mydiv">
</div>
.......
```

*myjsfile.js*

```
............
$("#mydiv").load("myphpfile.html");
............
```

*myphpfile.html*

```
............
<?php
    include("myfile.php");
?>
............
```

The content of *myphpfile.php* is not viewed. How can I show the content of *myphpfile.php* in selected div?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you load directly to myfile.php?

Comment: `$("#mydiv").load("myfile.php");` ?

Comment: change the extension of myphpfile.html to myphpfile.php

Comment: Write code in PHP file not in HTML

Comment: wait... `$("#mydiv").load("myphpfile.html");`, is on document ready?

Comment: why does you including a .php file into a file with extension .html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php also in load funtion.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
         $("#mydiv").load("myfile.php");
});
```

Above code will load after page loaded

```
include("myfile.php");
```

include function will run before loading html and javascript codes..

Use this script file for library **[jquery-1.9.1.js](http://harikarank.com/lib/js/jquery-1.9.1.js)**

Answer (score 0):

We could not able to include PHP file with in HTML file. You have to call php file instead of HTML file.
In PHP, there are many function to include Myfile.php file. please find the include function as below:

include()

require()

include_once()

require_once()